# Regex matches "test" not "test-1"

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regular expression in java, and I have written following expression to find my search strings.

```
String regex = "(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-|]*" + searchString + "(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-|]*";
```

I have two `String`s stored in DB as "testEcho" and "testEcho-1".

When I pass "test" as my search `String`, the above regex pattern returns only the "testEcho" as the result. But it has to return both strings. What is wrong in my regex?

Comment: check out regexpal.com, valuable tool for debugging regular expressions

Comment: You don't need `(?i)` twice in your regex. Also instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_` you can use `\\w`.

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to put `(?i)` in the second string literal, unless you think `searchString` might have `(?-i)` in it.  The search routines will see this as one big string--it won't know that it was composed of three parts in the above expression.  So the second `(?i)` is redundant.  Also, if there's any chance `searchString` could have characters that are special to regexes, you should change it to `Pattern.quote(searchString)` unless you *want* them to be special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `-`, like this `[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-|]`, otherwise it thinks its a range `.-|`, which doesn't make sense.

Also, there is no need for the double `(?i)` as the first one lasts till the end.
You can also shorten up the class to this (but it doesn't matter) `[\w.\-|]`.
You can even put the `-` at the beginning or end in the class and its treated as a literal,  instead of a range operator.

You can also make the class quantifier non-greedy by adding a question mark `*?`.

Another thing to watch out for is the searchString itself, each character should be
escaped or some of its characters could be interpreted as regex metachar's.

Suggested regex:

`String regex = "(?i)[\\w.|-]*?" + EscapedsearchString + "[\\w.|-]*?";`

Comment: aack, you need to double the backslashes in the string literals

Answer (score 2):

Your character class has an error:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.-|]
```

needs to be

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.|-]
```

Otherwise, the `-` is not treated as a  literal `-` but tries to construct a character range between `.` (ASCII 46) and `|` (ASCII 124), just like in `A-Z`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a hyphen in a character class like that without escaping it. That effectively allows any character with an ASCII value between that of `.` and `|`. Instead, escape the hyphen:

```
"(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\-|]*" + searchString + "(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.\\-|]*"
```

You can also put the hyphen at the beginning or end of a character class without escaping - just not in the middle.