# Java Pattern matcher evaluates the regex wrong?

Tags: java, regex

I followed the all answers provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878699/regex-matches-test-not-test-1) (i originally posted that question)
and changed my regular expression like that.

For example, my regular expression is now,

```
  String regex = "(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.|-]*" + searchString + "(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.|-]*";
```

I wnat to return "testEcho" and "testEcho-1" as my search output , when i do search using "test" as my searchstring.

But still i couldnt return testEcho and testEcho-1 as my result when i serch for "test" string.

My java code is;

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Name)

if (matcher.matches()) {
return XXX;
}
```

Any help?

Edit:

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
 Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher("testEcho")

    matcher1.matches --------->returns true

Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher("testEcho-1")

 matcher2.matches --------->returns false
```

Comment: What's the input? What output did you get? What did you expect? What's that return XXX?

Comment: Have you tried with `matcher.find()`?

Comment: input i s "test", expected output is "testEcho" and "testEcho-1".But now im getting only "testEcho"

Comment: With input, I meant, the strings on which you perform the regex test.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you post simple but full code example that we could use to reproduce your problem. Right now I am not sure why for `"test"` result should be `"testEcho"` and `"testEcho-1"`. Also shouldn't there be `"testEcho"` OR `"testEcho-1"`? Or maybe you want to return array or collenction that will contain `"testEcho"` and `"testEcho-1"`?

Comment: a wild guess - input are "testEcho" and "testEcho-1" strings and the pattern `(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.|-]*test(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9_.|-]*` is expected to match both, but it actually matches only "testEcho"

Comment: hi all, There are two strings stored in DB as "testEcho" and "testEcho-1". I expected to return both strings when i pass "test" as my serachString. in the above code, "Name" variable would be textEcho/testEcho-1. Now im getting 'testEcho" as only my out put. matcher returns false for "testEcho-1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your input data looks like but you probably

- should use `find` instead of `matches`,
- need to either escape `-` in character class with `\\-` or place it at its start `[-...]` or end `[...-]`.
- can replace `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\\w`.
- escape regex meta-characters from `searchString` using `Pattern.quote()`

so your regex can look like

```
String regex = "(?i)[\\w.|-]*" + Pattern.quote(searchString) + "[\\w.|-]*";
```

Try this way

```
public static List<String> giveMe(String searchString, String input) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String regex = "(?i)[\\w.|-]*" + Pattern.quote(searchString) + "[\\w.|-]*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        results.add(matcher.group());
    }

    return results;
}
```

demo

```
System.out.println(giveMe("test","This is some string with testEcho " +
        "and even testEcho-1 that I want to parse."));
```

output:

```
[testEcho, testEcho-1]
```

---

[edit]
Judging by your example you want to check if entire string matches specified regex. In that case maybe try this method

```
public static boolean canFind(String searchString, String input) {
    return input.matches("(?i)[\\w.|-]*" + Pattern.quote(searchString)
            + "[\\w.|-]*");
}
```

demo

```
System.out.println(canFind("test", "testEcho" ));//true
System.out.println(canFind("test", "TestEcho-1"));//true
System.out.println(canFind("test", "WestEcho-1"));//false
```

Comment: This also seems not working for me :(

Comment: @Ratha could you check my updated answer?

Comment: your sample code works perfect..Couldnt find what im doing wrong from my end..Thanks a lot, ill check more..

Comment: You should quote the searchString when building the regex: Pattern.quote(searchString)

Comment: @Ratha it is hard to say what is wrong with your code without seeing its full version. Your regex  (even if it could be improved) should work correctly http://ideone.com/YciSXy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only have 1 set of flags for 1 regex pattern even in Java, and if you are ignoring case, there's no need for *[a-zA-Z]*:

```
String regex = "(?i)[a-z0-9_.|-]*" + searchString + "[a-z0-9_.|-]*";
```